# Game over, man ... Game over

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

On February 25, 2017 Bill Paxton, one of only two actors to have the distinction of being [killed by a Xenomorph, a Predator *and* a Terminator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHg6S4AYlb4), passed away due to complications from surgery.

Sci-fi fans will best remember him for his role in Aliens (as Pvt. <s>Hicks</s> Hudson) and his memorable line

> That's it, man. Game over, man. [Game over!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsx2vdn7gpY)

as well as his parts in Terminator, Predator 2, Thunderbirds and Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

**Our thoughts and prayers go out to his family and friends. He will be missed.**

Comment: `The world is a lesser place for his passing, and I will profoundly miss him.` - [James Cameron](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/02/james-cameron-bill-paxton)

Comment: And _Twister_! "We got cows!" "Another cow.." "Actually I think that was the same one."

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace No, but this is Meta, not everything *has* to be a question here.

Comment: He'll always be my favorite sleazy cars salesman

Comment: The answers on this post made me realise I knew this actor more than I knew I did.

Answer (score 20):

My favorite Sci-fi/Fantasy Bill Paxton roles are:

**Chet Donnelly from [Weird Science](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090305/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_75)** - I know that he has done so much with his acting career since this movie, but I always think of Chet Donnelly whenever I think of Bill Paxton.

[image: Chet Donnelly]

**Punk Leader from [The Terminator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_78)** - This was an extremely small, but memorable role.
[image: Punk Leader]

**Private Hudson from [Aliens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_72)** - This is one of my favorite roles of his and absolutely has to be mentioned!  How can anyone forget Hudson and his many memorable quotes from that movie?  That movie would not have been the same without him!

[image: Hudson]

**R.I.P Bill Paxton.**
Thank you for providing us with years of entertainment and with so many memorable characters.  My heart is absolutely broken right now.  You will be missed by all of your fans.

Comment: Weird science! OH man, I watched that so much as a kid! 

My fave is _Twister_, though.

Answer (score 5):

Let us all remember Bill with a few rousing games of his very own [pinball machine](https://www.benheck.com/bill-paxton-pinball/). RIP Simon, you slimy, lovable bastard.

[image]